# Error in Spring bean of JMSPublisher using JMS AMQ topic

Tags: java, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I am trying to create Spring bean of JMS with ActiveMQ in following way:

```xml
<!-- Spring JMS Template -->
<bean id="refreshJmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory">
        <ref bean="refreshJmsFactory"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Queue -->
<amq:topic id="refreshTopic" physicalName="SystemRefreshTopic"/>

<!-- Publisher -->
<bean id="refreshPublisher" scope="prototype"
      class="com.pubsub.publisher.JMSRefreshMessagePublisher" init-method="init">
    <property name="destination" ref="refreshTopic"/>
    <property name="jmsTemplate" ref="refreshJmsTemplate"/>
</bean>
```

Java definition of RefreshMessagePublisher is as follows:

```java
public class JMSRefreshMessagePublisher implements RefreshMessagePublisher, ApplicationContextAware {

    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    private ActiveMQDestination destination;

    private ApplicationContext appContext;

    /*
        init() method to be called during bean init
     */
    public void init(String beanName, ApplicationContext appContext) {
        final String topic = SystemConstants.SYSTEM_REFRESH_TOPIC + "_" + beanName;
        final ActiveMQDestination destination = new ActiveMQTopic(topic);
        this.setDestination(destination);
    }


    private void setDestination(ActiveMQDestination destination) {
        this.destination = destination;
    }

    public void setJmsTemplate(JmsTemplate jmsTemplate) {
        this.jmsTemplate = jmsTemplate;
    }
```

When instantiating the bean i am getting following error

```
Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'destination' of bean class [com.pubsub.publisher.SystemRefreshMessagePublisher]: Bean property 'destination' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```